# How to redirect driverquery using cmd output to file when executed in C#

Tags: c#

I am using the below code in my program and the output file is not being generated. Any idea what might I be doing wrong in this case?

```
using (StreamWriter fileWriter = new StreamWriter(tempDirectory+@"\drivertable.txt"))
        {
            using (Process driverQuery = new Process())
            {
                if (File.Exists(Environment.SystemDirectory + @"\driverquery.exe"))
                {
                    driverQuery.StartInfo.FileName = "driverquery.exe";
                    driverQuery.StartInfo.Arguments = @"/FO table /v >> C:\text.txt";
                    Console.WriteLine(driverQuery.StartInfo.Arguments);
                    driverQuery.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = false;
                    driverQuery.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
                    driverQuery.Start();
                    //fileWriter.WriteLine(driverQuery.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());
                    driverQuery.WaitForExit();
                    fileWriter.Close();


                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Driverquery.exe not found in system");
                }

            }
        }
```

The `>>` is giving me the problem in executing. I know I can do this via the StreamWriter as well but this seems a better option.

Thanks!

Comment: '>>" is not a command argument.  It is standard output.  So you need to make RedirectStandardOutput = true.  Then in your code you need to capture the standard output and save into c:\text.txt in your C# code.

Comment: So, in other words, I cannot use the ">>" directive in C# like I use in CMD?

Comment: Nope.  The Arguments and the Standard output are two separate objects.  The arguments will not accept standard output as an item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the comments by @jdweng, it seems that it is not possible.